# What is the correct way to import a js class into a Svelte component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, svelte

I have a `SomeClass.ts` like:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor () {
    console.log('created someclass')
  }
}

export default SomeClass
```

Which compiles to `SomeClass.js`

```js
'use strict'
exports.__esModule = true
const SomeClass = /** @class */ (function () {
  function SomeClass () {
    console.log('created someclass')
  }
  return SomeClass
}())
exports.default = SomeClass
```

And is imported into the script tag of `App.svelte` like:

```html
<script>
  import SomeClass from "./SomeClass";

  const instance = new SomeClass();
</script>
```

But when running the app I get error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default`

on generated line: `import SomeClass from "/src/SomeClass.js?t=1655451078055";`

Note:

Just using regular ES6 flavour class & `export default MyClass` in SomeClass.js works fine, but might as well just remove Typescript...

---

Installed svelte-preprocess

`npm install -D svelte-preprocess`

Updated `vite.config.js` like so:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess' // <--- added this

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte({
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess() // <--- added this
  })]
})
```

Deleted the compiled .js and now just work with the Typescript file directly no problems!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is compiled with a different module system (CommonJS) than what is expected by Svelte (ES module).

I would not recommend compiling the class separately but instead to use [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) and import/use the TypeScript source directly in the component, by using a `<script lang="ts">` tag. Then the class should be compiled alongside the component code.

If the class is not used anywhere else you could probably also change the `module` option to `"esnext"` in the corresponding `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Amazing thank you! Documentation on svelte-preprocess mostly describes rollup instead of vite but it works a treat right away.